# regex, negative lookahead (?!?) find < tags not followed by?

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

How to find `<` tags not followed by `?`

```
$htmlStr = " ba <div>b <? </div>n";
$regex1 = '#<#'; // finds 3 '<' 
$regex2 = '#<(?!?)#'; // does not find anyhting, although should find two '<' not followed by '?'
```

Comment: You should get a `nothing to repeat` error when trying to run this...

Comment: yes, the error is as you said. ALso `'#<[^?]#'` is not working

Answer (score 1):

`?` is a special character in your regexp pattern and should be escaped:

```
$htmlStr = " ba <div>b <? </div>n";
$regex2 = '#<(?!\?)#';   // <-- will find 2 matches
```